# Will installing Ubuntu erase the whole disk or will it still preserve GRUB?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive

I have a PC running Ubuntu 20.04.

I noticed that starting this PC from live Ubuntu DVD (try Ubuntu without making any changes Option) and then formatting the SSD will not wipe the whole system.

When I later start the PC it still loads GRUB but nothing happens then.

My question is: When I install Ubuntu and choose to “Erase the Disk” from the installation option will Ubuntu erase the disk but still preserve GRUB or will be everything erased?

Answer (score 0):

When you are erasing "the disk" the Master Boot Record (MBR) is generally not destroyed.   If you want to wipe out the MBR you can use `dd`to overwrite it with 0's.

Answer (score 0):

Unless some data is written over the boot partition, it will still be recognized. If you erase the disk and then overwrite it with ubuntu depending on the location it will be removed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).